# Access request headers in envoy_on_response

Tags: lua, envoyproxy

Is it possible to access any request headers sent by client when envoy_on_response. This is to modify a response header based on a condition on request header.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Lua filter by using the [Dynamic Metadata object API](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.28.0/configuration/http/http_filters/lua_filter#dynamic-metadata-object-api). Here's an example below that will:

- read the `x-my-header` header from the request
- set a header `x-my-header-is-a` in the response according to `x-my-header` value:

  - if `x-my-header` is `A`, it will set `x-my-header-is-a: true`
  - otherwise, it will set `x-my-header-is-a: false`

The trick here is to use the Dynamic Metadata struct to share things between `envoy_on_request` and `envoy_on_response`.

With `/etc/lua/filter.lua`:

```lua
function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
  -- store "x-my-header" in the dynamic metadata
  request_handle:streamInfo():dynamicMetadata():set("envoy.filters.http.lua",
    "x-my-header", request_handle:headers():get("x-my-header")
  )
end

function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
  -- retrieve "x-my-header" from the dynamic metadata
  local my_header = response_handle:streamInfo():dynamicMetadata():get("envoy.filters.http.lua")["x-my-header"]
  
  -- insert your custom logic here; in this dummy example, set "x-my-header-is-a" according to "x-my-header"
  if my_header == "A" then
    response_handle:headers():add("x-my-header-is-a", "true")
  else
    response_handle:headers():add("x-my-header-is-a", "false")
  end
end
```

You can use it in your envoy config like this:

```yaml
http_filters:
  - name: envoy.filters.http.lua
    typed_config:
      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
      default_source_code:
        filename: /etc/lua/filter.lua
  # other filters
```

I've tested it with envoy v1.28.0, and it works perfectly:

```bash
$ # test 1, no "x-my-header" header in the request
$ curl -s -I localhost:8080 | grep "x-my-header-is-a"
x-my-header-is-a: false

$ # test 2, header "x-my-header" = "A" in the request
$ curl -s -I -H "x-my-header: A" localhost:8080 | grep "x-my-header-is-a"
x-my-header-is-a: true

$ # test 3, header "x-my-header" != "A" in the request
$ curl -s -I -H "x-my-header: B" localhost:8080 | grep "x-my-header-is-a" 
x-my-header-is-a: false
```

Credit also goes to this answer here: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/4613#issuecomment-701799475.